# Spring boot MultipartFile request returns 404

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data, multipartfile

I make post multipart request and get 404

see that:
[the path is correct!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za5AL.png)

here it is my controlller:
[my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skve5.png)

here it is my Bean:
[Bean registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfQQa.png)

Please note that i dont get any error!!
Only 404

What can be the isssue?
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to understand why i am getting 404 error

Answer (score 2):

Changing the annotation of the controller class from @Controller to @RestController solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
I have found the issue
I have 2 kind of controllers
1 - Javax (Jakarta) controller with prefix "rest"
2 - Spring Controller (that i tried to create) with same "rest prefix

I understood that we cannot have those different controllers with same prefix this causes a conflict
I have just renamed the second prefix to "restapi" and both are working!
It took me 2 weeks to resolve it :)